# $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$, prove $\sum\frac{2+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+c}+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8abc}\ge\frac{39}{8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, uvw

> Let $a,b,c> 0: ab+bc+ca+abc=4.$ Prove that: $$\frac{2+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+c}+\frac{2+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+a}+\frac{2+\sqrt{ca}}{\sqrt{ca}+b}+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8abc}\ge\frac{39}{8}.$$

I try  a well-known substitution $a=\dfrac{2x}{y+z}$ but I don't know how to continue because it is very complicated.

Also, if we set $a\rightarrow a^2,...$ and $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2b^2c^2=4,$ we will prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab+2}{ab+c^2}+\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{8a^2b^2c^2}\ge\frac{39}{8}$$
I think we can expand all and use $pqr$ method. So far, I am stuck here.

Please help me some better ideas. Thank you very much

**Update**

Is it possible to expanding all yields and how to end it ?

Comment: You shoud expand all since almost using inequalities step will lead to wrong one. For example, $$\frac{2+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+c}+\frac{2+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+a}+\frac{2+\sqrt{ca}}{\sqrt{ca}+b}\le \frac{9}{2},$$ which is not true

Comment: Could you please give me a hint ?

Comment: I have no nice proof now

Comment: Now I see a very nice proof. Show me more progress. For example, what did you get after clearing denominator, etc

Comment: @TATAbox can you kindly enlighten us with your proof? It's been 3 months now 

Comment: @HamLemon I almost forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof.**

We can use the isolated fudging idea.

Indeed, we will prove $$\frac{2+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+a}\ge 2-\frac{2a}{a+b+c+bc}. \tag{1}$$
Taking cylic sum on $(1)$ it remains to prove that$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+9abc}{16abc}\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+bc}, \tag{2}$$which is true by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Can you end it now ?

---

Indeed, by CBS
\begin{align*}
    \frac{2+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+a}&=\frac{\sqrt{[a(b+c+bc)+bc][4a(b+c+bc)+(b+c+bc-a)^2]}+\sqrt{bc}(a+b+c+bc)}{\left(\sqrt{bc}+a\right)(a+b+c+bc)}\\&\ge \frac{2a(b+c+bc)+\sqrt{bc}(b+c+bc-a)+\sqrt{bc}(a+b+c+bc)}{\left(\sqrt{bc}+a\right)(a+b+c+bc)}\\&=\frac{2(b+c+bc)}{a+b+c+bc}.
\end{align*}
It implies$$\frac{2+\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+a}\ge 2-\frac{2a}{a+b+c+bc}. $$
Now, by using Cauchy - Schwarz$$\frac{a}{a+b+c+bc}=\frac{a}{3.\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}+bc}\le \frac{a}{16bc}+\frac{9a}{16(a+b+c)}.$$Similarly, we obtain $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+bc}\le \sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{16bc}+\frac{9}{16}=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+9abc}{16abc}.$$
We end proof here. Equality holds at $a=b=c=1.$

Comment: It is very nice.

Comment: Is there a nice proof for $(1)$ ?

Comment: @Dragonboy Of course, I'll post it soon. Very busy now.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of a proof.**

We use the so-called isolated fudging.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+c} + \frac{a^2 + b^2}{16abc} \ge \frac{39}{8}\cdot \frac{6a + 6b + abc}{12(a + b + c) + 3abc}. \tag{1}$$
(*Note*: Take cyclic sum on (1), we get the desired inequality.)

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*. I have a complicated proof below.
I will try to find a better proof of (1) (e.g. by hand).

$\phantom{2}$

Let $p = a + b, q = ab$. Then
$$p^2 \ge 4q, \quad 0 < q \le 4. \tag{2}$$
Using $c = \frac{4 - ab}{ab + a + b} = \frac{4 - q}{p + q}$, (1) is written as
$$\frac{2+\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt{q} + \frac{4 - q}{p + q}} + \frac{p^2 - 2q}{16q \cdot \frac{4 - q}{p + q}} \ge \frac{39}{8}\cdot \frac{6p + q \cdot \frac{4 - q}{p + q}}{12p + 12 \cdot \frac{4 - q}{p + q} + 3q \cdot \frac{4 - q}{p + q}}. \tag{3}$$

It suffices to prove that (3) is true for all $0 < q \le 4$ and $p\ge \sqrt{4q}$.

Let
$$u = \frac{2 - \sqrt{q}}{\sqrt{q}} \ge 0,
\quad v = p - \sqrt{4q} \ge 0.$$
Then
$$q = \frac{4}{(1 + u)^2}, \quad p = \frac{4}{1 + u} + v.$$

(3) is written as
$$m_6 v^6 + m_5 v^5 + m_4 v^4 + m_3v^3 + m_2v^2 + m_1 v + m_0 \ge 0 \tag{4}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 m_6 &= {u}^{10}+10\,{u}^{9}+45\,{u}^{8}+120\,{u}^{7}+210\,{u}^{6}+252\,{u}^{5
 }\\
&\qquad +210\,{u}^{4}+120\,{u}^{3}+45\,{u}^{2}+10\,u+1,\\
m_5 &= 2\,{u}^{11}+22\,{u}^{10}+132\,{u}^{9}+540\,{u}^{8}+1548\,{u}^{7}+3108
\,{u}^{6}\\
&\qquad +4368\,{u}^{5}+4272\,{u}^{4}+2850\,{u}^{3}+1238\,{u}^{2}+316
\,u+36,\\
m_4 &= 44\,{u}^{10}+456\,{u}^{9}+2316\,{u}^{8}+7616\,{u}^{7}+17572\,{u}^{6}+
28824\,{u}^{5}\\
&\qquad +33196\,{u}^{4}+26096\,{u}^{3}+13296\,{u}^{2}+3952\,u+
520,\\
m_3 &= 8\,{u}^{11}+88\,{u}^{10}+1056\,{u}^{9}+6784\,{u}^{8}+24792\,{u}^{7}+
59448\,{u}^{6}\\
&\qquad +102064\,{u}^{5}+128688\,{u}^{4}+115792\,{u}^{3}+69344\,
{u}^{2}+24448\,u+3808,\\
m_2 &= 96\,{u}^{10}-256\,{u}^{9}-2208\,{u}^{8}+4960\,{u}^{7}+51200\,{u}^{6}+
142048\,{u}^{5}\\
&\qquad +224512\,{u}^{4}+237760\,{u}^{3}+171072\,{u}^{2}+74752
\,u+14592,\\
m_1 &= 1344\,{u}^{9}+3392\,{u}^{8}-12736\,{u}^{7}-51136\,{u}^{6}-37760\,{u}^{
 5}+59520\,{u}^{4}\\
&\qquad +138752\,{u}^{3}+141312\,{u}^{2}+90112\,u+26624,\\
m_0 &= 4352\,{u}^{8}+19968\,{u}^{7}+15616\,{u}^{6}-34816\,{u}^{5}-33792\,{u}^
{4}\\
&\qquad +16384\,{u}^{3}-4096\,{u}^{2}+16384.
\end{align*}

Clearly, $m_6, m_5, m_4, m_3 \ge 0$ (all coefficients are non-negative). It suffices to prove that
$$m_2 v^2 + m_1 v + m_0 \ge 0. \tag{5}$$

It is easy to prove that $m_2, m_0 \ge 0$. By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$2\sqrt{m_2 m_0} + m_1 \ge 0$$
which is true.

Comment: Nice solution! It is the best here.

Comment: @Dragonboy TATA box's solution is better.

Comment: Oh, now I see it.